# iptables help - How to route guest network through wan firewall/port forwarding rules?

Tags: router, iptables, tomato

I have my network segmented into 2 parts:

1. Private Network - only trusted personal devices connected (wired & wireless), webserver, etc. and has outbound internet access. Also allowed access to * ALL* devices on both Private & Guest networks.
2. Guest/IOT Network - has outbound internet access, but should not see/access private network. For guests and untrusted IOT devices

I setup iptables rules to allow me to administer devices on Guest/IOT network from my private network (only if connection originates from private) but prevents any connections originating from guest attempting to access private net.

I have a few web services that I want Guest/IOT to be able to access as if they were coming from external internet, however.

I've tried forwarding br1 to "wanin" chain, but that allows everything (since there's no explicit DROP defined on my the "wanin" chain).   Is it safe to add a final DROP rule on "wanin" chain or will that cause problems?

***QUESTION:*** What's the best way to allow Guest/IOT network limited access to private network as if it were coming from WAN/internet so only external exposed services are accessible?

My router is flashed with tomato firmware and runs the firewall configuration.  Below are the sections of my iptables config that relate (some entries removed for clarity)

```
# Generated by iptables-save
*filter
:INPUT DROP [80:9315]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2100:759842]
:monitor - [0:0]
:shlimit - [0:0]
:upnp - [0:0]
:wanin - [0:0]
:wanout - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m account --aaddr 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 --aname lan
-A FORWARD -m account --aaddr 172.16.1.0/255.255.255.0 --aname lan1
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br1 -o br1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -j upnp
-A wanin -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 192.168.1.200 -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 192.168.1.200 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 192.168.1.200 -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually need a DROP rule if the default policy is DROP (unless you used `-j` for chain(s) instead of `-g` and want to avoid "returning" / further matching).

So you can do:

```
-A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -g wanin
```

I don't think you really want to allow UDP 80 and 443 by the way.

You don't really need the extra rule that matches conntrack state and the interfaces at the same time. The RELATED/ESTABLISHED states already imply/require that.

Note that rules in each chain are matched in order. Having these rules would mean all traffics (except the ones you drop earlier) from these interfaces and go out via any interfaces:

```
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br1 -j ACCEPT
```

and what actually get dropped by this:

```
-A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -j DROP
```

depends on when you append it.

There may not be necessary unless the each of the bridges includes hosts that are of different IP subnets and made to communicate with indirect route (via the "router part of the router"):

```
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br1 -o br1 -j ACCEPT
```